# Fan speed always at maximum, how to solve?

Tags: 20.04, cpu, fan, temperature

Suddenly during use the fan starts and stays at maximum.
I notice from the report below that the temperature is very high. How can I isolate the problem?

```
inxi -Fxpmzr
System:
  Kernel: 5.19.0-45-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.5
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP ProBook 455 G7 v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8730 v: KBC Version 13.26.00 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: HP v: S79 Ver. 01.08.00 date: 01/17/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 27.1 Wh (90.9%) condition: 29.8/45.0 Wh (66.3%)
    volts: 11.7 min: 11.4 model: Hewlett-Packard Primary status: Charging
  Device-1: hidpp_battery_0 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse MX Master 3
    charge: 100% (should be ignored) status: Discharging
Memory:
  RAM: total: 15.03 GiB used: 8.54 GiB (56.8%)
  RAM Report:
    permissions: Unable to run dmidecode. Root privileges required.
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MCP arch: Zen 2 rev: 1 cache: L1: 512 KiB L2: 4 MiB L3: 8 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2156 high: 3736 min/max: 1400/2000 boost: enabled
    cores: 1: 1397 2: 1403 3: 1397 4: 1398 5: 3736 6: 3002 7: 1935 8: 2980
    bogomips: 31938
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: amdgpu v: kernel
    bus-ID: 05:00.0
  Device-2: Cheng Uei Precision Industry (Foxlink) HP Wide Vision HD
    Integrated Webcam
    type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-4:2
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu resolution:
    1: 1920x1080 2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: RENOIR (renoir LLVM 15.0.6 DRM 3.47 5.19.0-45-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 05:00.1
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: N/A bus-ID: 05:00.5
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 05:00.6
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-45-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus-ID: 02:00.0
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-3: Realtek RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter type: USB
    driver: r8152 bus-ID: 2-1.3:6
  IF: enx002432187fbf state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX200 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-3:3
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 46.71 GiB (9.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Intel model: SSDPEKNW512G8H size: 476.94 GiB
    temp: 41.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.89 GiB used: 46.71 GiB (10.0%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 114.2 MiB (5.6%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 83.0 C mobo: 0.0 C gpu: amdgpu temp: 59.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 1938
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
    1: deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
    2: deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
    3: deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
    4: deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
    5: deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
    6: deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
    7: deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    8: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
    9: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
    10: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yuezk-ubuntu-globalprotect-openconnect-jammy.list
    1: deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/yuezk/globalprotect-openconnect/ubuntu/ jammy main
Info:
  Processes: 381 Uptime: 7h 17m Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers:
  gcc: 11.3.0 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: Usually there is a process running, which heats up the CPU (or GPU). Hopefully this is not a system process and can be stopped. Identify the process with `top` (see `man top`) or another process monitoring tool.

Comment: 83C is toasty, what is your CPU utilization?